# dragging images placed in a UItableViewCell to another uitableviewcell in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, drag-and-drop

I am new to iphone app development.

I have placed images in UITableView as an image gallery,in rows and columns.

Now, I want to drag images with in the tableview,by which position of images can be changed.
I have searched for it, but I didnt find any proper solution.
It will be like

UIView

--TableView

---TableViewCell

----custom UIView

-----ImageViews

A row in a table view contain more than one image.

Also if we clicked on an image, should open another view showing full image.

Please can anyone help me..,thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm looking at doing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the ur TableViewCell with ur gesture recognizer for Dragging then add it to the tableview as cell for each ,then

1.if u have only images in cell

interchange the tableviewcells

2.if u have images and some labeltext

set the cell.image property to the first dragging cell.

that's it